# How to make this like of dropdown in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[Dropdown like this with icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZbed.png)
When user will click the top or bottom arrow, item will select and display.

Answer (score 0):

This is from their [doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html). You can choose first item, leading icon, control what happens when button is clicked with onChanged etc. I am not sure if this is what youre looking for though

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  String dropdownValue = 'One';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      iconSize: 24,
      elevation: 16,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newValue!;
        });
      },
      items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's another form that partially fulfilled my requirement. I want to scroll up when clicking up arrow click and scroll down when click down arrow button from dropdown list. It can be happened not displaying whole list item in dropdown. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Yeah I was not quite sure about what you wanted but seems like your solution with modifying dropdown button is a pretty valid one. You're welcome